# Drupal 7: Hooks for entity references

Tags: drupal, reference, drupal-hooks, drupal-entities

Is it possible to hook on changes of entity references?
Let's say I have `a <- b` and `b <- x -> a`.
when `a <- b` changes to `d <- b` I want also `b <- x -> a` to change to `b <- x -> d`

Answer (score 0):

Where is the field at? My first inclination would be to use hook_entity_update. But you could catch all entities using: hook_field_update

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_update/7